# Julia WebSocket slow to read/write

Tags: http, websocket, julia, latency

I was testing Julia WebSockets and I found that they are much slower than the Python/Node equivalents. I wrote a test to send a ping and measure the time taken for a pong response from some crypto exchanges as an example. Julia consistently takes 50ms for the test below, whereas python takes 2-4 ms. Is this expected?

Julia:

```
using WebSockets
function main()
    WebSockets.open("wss://wsaws.okex.com:8443/ws/v5/public") do ws
        for i = 1:100
            a = time_ns()
            write(ws, "ping")
            data, success = readguarded(ws)
            b = time_ns()
            println(String(data), " ", (b - a) / 1000000)
            sleep(0.1)
        end
    end
end
main()
```

Equivalent Python:

```
import websockets
import asyncio
import time

async def main():
    uri = "wss://wsaws.okex.com:8443/ws/v5/public"
    async with websockets.connect(uri) as websocket:
        msg = "hello"
        for i in range(101):
            a = time.time()
            await websocket.send(msg)
            x = await websocket.recv()
            b = time.time()
            print(b-a)
            time.sleep(0.1)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
```

Comment: Better to file an issue at https://github.com/JuliaWeb/WebSockets.jl/issues . Based on my test, it takes about 0.25s for the Julia version and about 0.1s for the Python version.